# Is it a good idea to use Service as Presenter in MVP context

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-service, mvp

Short stated my question is: in MVP architecture is it a good idea to use a Service as
Presenter to control a Model implemented as Service ?

Alternative question: Is using a Service to control another Service a good idea ?

### The context:

I am writing an app that communicates with a bluetooth sensor.
The app has a [Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html)
 (aka `BluetoothService`) that makes the connection and manages the communication with the sensor.
The app has several Fragments but just few of them are related to the operations that
 the Bluetooth sensor does. A user should be able to start an operation, navigates to different
 fragments and later watches the results of the operation(s) done by the sensor.

### My purpose:

I want to write a component (aka `BluetoothController`) that makes the links
between the sensor (represented in my app by `BluetoothService`) and the rest of
 the app. The `BluetoothController` contains Objects that described what kind of
  operation has to be done by the sensor (only one operation, serial operations,
   type of the operation, ...), so `BluetoothController` 's purpose is to let
   the operations be independant to Bluetooth sensor and then be able to test the app
    with a mock bluetooth class. I see `BluetoothService` as a model and
    `BluetoothController` as a presenter, am I wrong ?

### Why a Service:

- Because it does not die if the user navigates between fragments
- Because it is accessible through the whole app via `bindService`
- Because `bindService` is the only entry point, I guess I can control that just
  one operation is done at a time
- Because I see Service as an active component, so it can keep on receiving data even if there is nothing bound to it

This service would be both started and bind (like a music player):

- to be able to keep on running even if no components are bound to it,
- to ease communication

All services would be in the application process to let communication be done
without binder but rather
method call.

Any suggestion would be highly appreciate , thanks in advance

### Why not something else:

- RetainedFragment are (for me) just container
- pojo presenter are just gateway between views and models, they should die if
  they are not attached to a view.

### Conclusion

Am I wrong? Do you see difficulties in this architecture? Are there other Android
components that suits my purpose better?

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated, thank you in advances

Comment: You could try [this approach](https://medium.com/@czyrux/presenter-surviving-orientation-changes-with-loaders-6da6d86ffbbf#.q666x5wyc). It could be combined with dagger2, so loader would provide PresenterComponent, not just particular presenter